# Android SQLITE not working

Tags: database

Guys I was testing my sql code in a demo application but i am getting an error like this:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Phone": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Create table SMS(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT Phone TEXT Msg TEXT Hour INTEGER Min INTEGER);
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)

                                                                                                                                                                                at com.example.cyberpaths.myapplication.DBHandler.onCreate(DBHandler.java:38)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
                                                                                      at com.example.cyberpaths.myapplication.DBHandler.printsms(DBHandler.java:65)
                                                                                      at com.example.cyberpaths.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
```

My database oncreate code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query="Create table "+TABLE_NAME+"("+
                COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT "+
                COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT " +
                COLUMN_MSG + " TEXT " +
                COLUMN_HOUR + " INTEGER " +
                COLUMN_MIN + " INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL(query);
        SMS ob=new SMS("9836632841","hii",15,5);
        addSMS(ob);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing all commas between the column definitions. Just print out what you're running.